# Subspace of matrices AB = BA

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stuck with the following exercise:

Let A be an $n\times n$ diagonal matrix with characteristic polynomial:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{k}(x-c_{i})^{d_{i}}$$

where $c_{1},...,c_{k}$ are distinct.

Let $W$ be the space of all matrices $n\times n$ B such that AB=BA.

Prove that the dimension of $W$ is $$\sum_{i=1}^{k}d_{i}^{2}$$

Possibly relevant things include:

$A$ is diagonalizable IFF $p_{cA}=\prod_{i=1}^{k}(x-c_{i})^{d_{i}}$ where $d_{i}=\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{ker}(T-c_{i}I))$ IFF $\sum_{i=1}^{k}d_{i}= \operatorname{dim}V$

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $B$ must map each of the subspaces $\text{ker}(T - c_i I)$ into itself.
Of matrices with a single $1$ and every other entry $0$, which ones do that?

Comment: Matrices with a single 1 in the diagonal and 0s elsewhere commute with A, but I'm not sure how that helps

Answer (score 0):

Let $e_j$ be the $j$th standard basis vector.  Since $A$ is diagonal, $e_j$ is an eigenvector with eigenvector $\lambda_j$ (the $j$th diagonal entry).  We must have
$$
ABe_j = BAe_j = \lambda_jBe_j
$$
That is, $Be_j$ (the $j$th column of $B$) must be an eigenvector of $A$ associated with $\lambda_j$.

So, for example, take
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&&\\&3&\\&&2}
$$
We could set $B(e_1)$ to just be $e_1$, but we could also set it to be $e_3$, or any linear combination $a e_1 + b e_3$.  Notably, we *can't* set it to be anything else.